# Format number without rounding, limitimg decimal places, operate futher on number

Tags: javascript, parsing, printing, numbers, rounding

I`d like to format decimal number **0.0003333333333333333** to **0.00033** without rounding.
Number is coming from division decimal numbers.
Also want to operate futher with number **0.00033**.

> *toFixed(), Math.round(), toPrecision()* are rounding so im not keeping eye on it.

I was thinking about parsing number to string, use slice and next parse text to number again.

*Code:*

```
let salesMixOld1 = document.querySelector("#sales-mix-old-1");
let cosOldPromo = document.querySelector("#cos-old-promo");
let salesMixOld2 = document.querySelector("#sales-mix-old-2");

let daysInMonth = document.querySelector("#days-in-month");
let howMuchDaysPromotion = document.querySelector("#how-much-days-promotion");

const calculateCosAll = () => {
    let parseCosAll = parseFloat(cosAll.value);
    let parseSalesMixOld1 = parseFloat(salesMixOld1.value);
    let parseCosOldPromo = parseFloat(cosOldPromo.value);
    let parseSalesMixOld2 = parseFloat(salesMixOld2.value);

    let resultCalculateCosAll = (parseCosAll - (parseCosOldPromo * parseSalesMixOld2)) / parseSalesMixOld1;

    calculatedCosAllDiv.innerHTML = resultCalculateCosAll;
}

const calculateSalesMixPerDay = () => {
    let parseSalesMixOld2 = parseFloat(salesMixOld2.value);
    let parsedaysInMonth = parseFloat(daysInMonth.value);
    let parsehowMuchDaysPromotion = parseFloat(howMuchDaysPromotion.value);

    let resultCalculateSalesMixMonth = parseSalesMixOld2 / parsedaysInMonth;
    let resultCalculateSalesMixDay = resultCalculateSalesMixMonth * parsehowMuchDaysPromotion;

    calculatedSalesMixDiv.innerHTML = resultCalculateSalesMixMonth + "/" + resultCalculateSalesMixDay;
}


calculateCosAllBtn.addEventListener('click', calculateCosAll);
calculateSalesMixBtn.addEventListener('click', calculateSalesMixPerDay);
```

Comment: multiply by the necessary power of 10 and then `Math.trunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid rounding you can multiply by the appropriate power of 10, call [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) which will return the integer part of a number discarding the decimal, and then divide again.

```js
const input = 0.000338;
const result = Math.trunc(input * 100_000) / 100_000;

console.log(result);
```

Or as a helper function

```js
function truncate(number, places) {
  return Math.trunc(number * 10 ** places) / 10 ** places;
}

const input = 0.000338;
console.log(truncate(input, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this one ?

```js
const num2precise = (num, decimals = 5) =>
  {
  let 
    s = num.toString()
  , p = s.indexOf('.')
    ;
  s += (p<0 ? (p=1+s.length, '.'):'') + '0'.repeat(decimals)
  return s.slice(0,p+1+decimals )
  }

console.log( num2precise( 0.0003333333333333333 )) //  0.00033
console.log( num2precise( 0.000339 ))              //  0.00033
console.log( num2precise( 0.0003 ))                //  0.00030
console.log( num2precise( 25 ))                    // 25.00000
console.log( num2precise( 25, 7 ))                 // 25.0000000
```

> if you prefer a Number value :

```js
const num2precise = (num, decimals = 5) =>
  {
  let 
    s = num.toString()
  , p = s.indexOf('.')
    ;
  return Number( (p<0) ? s : s.slice(0,p+1+decimals))
  }

console.log( num2precise( 0.0003333333333333333 )) //  0.00033
console.log( num2precise( 0.000339 ))              //  0.00033
console.log( num2precise( 0.0003 ))                //  0.0003 
console.log( num2precise( 25 ))                    // 25
```

Comment: but this returns strings

Comment: @pilchard  updated addition to return a Number type...

Answer (score -1):

```js
let number = 0.0003333333333333333;
Number(number).toFixed(4);
console.log(Number(number).toFixed(5));
//result 0.00033
```

Comment: What if number will be 0003333333333333355? to.Fixed() will round. Still want to 0.00033

Comment: wrong answer, `let number = 0.0003393333333333333;` return `0.00034`  you misread the question!

Comment: @Vizzini if you are looking round a number to # decimal place then you can get it by const result = Math.round(number * 10) / 10; but you need to know the (digit place)